# localizing asp.net controls with custom classes without resx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, resx

I have only 1 Label control in my test page called WebForm1.aspx.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" 
    meta:resourcekey="Label1Resource1"></asp:Label>
```

I would like to localize it with out using .resx file yet using the concept of meta:resourcekey.

Some how I would like to autogenerate a strongly type class based on the localizable controls on my web .aspx page.

This strongly typed class would read the resource value from the database and cache it as opposed to reading it from .resx file. I would like to completely stay from .resx file for now.

But I really like the concept of meta:resourcekey where all the controls in .aspx page auto-magically are localized based on .resx file.

Is it possible?

I have read through different pages on the internet and read up on things like ResXResourceReader and  PublicResXFileCodeGenerator and read several other article but none address this specific design issue that I am addressing here.

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott Guthrie posted some resources on this very topic.

[Extending the ASP.NET 2.0 Localization Model with a Database Resource Provider](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/29/extending-the-asp-net-2-0-localization-model-with-a-database-resource-provider.aspx)

It's old, but the concepts are still just as relevant.

**EDIT:**

The important link is dead, but can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx